# MVC4 - How do I pass IPagedList model to controller

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, paging

When Paging I am calling an action called `RentalSearchResults`

as in

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("RentalSearchResults", new { page } ))
```

The model thats passed is blank in the controller

should the action be like this?

```
public ActionResult RentalSearchResults(IPagedList<Mode> model)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you're only passing to the controller the page parameter.

```
public ActionResult RentalSearchResults(int? page)
{

}
```

If you want pass any additional parameter, you should do this:

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, 
    page => Url.Action("RentalSearchResults", 
    new 
    { 
       page,
       parameter1 = value1,
       parameter2 = value2
    }))
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult RentalSearchResults(int? page, string parameter1, string parameter2)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Create A PagerData Class and write a model binder for it

```
public class PagerData
{
  public int pageNumber{get;set;}
   //Add other properties
}

public class HomeCustomDataBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{

    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
      //TODO
    }

public ActionResult RentalSearchResults(PagerData pagerModel)
{

}
```